# How to use arguments and modules in python3

Tags: python

Please help.

I am doing this exercise, but I am using jupiter to do the exercise. This is written for python 2

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third virable is:", third)
```

How do I write it correctecly in Python 3 . Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do the same. No change.

Answer (score 0):

This same example works in Python 3 as well.

```

```
>> python unpack.py 4 5 3
The script is called: unpack.py
Your first variable is 4
Your second variable is: 5
Your third virable is: 3
```

```

You can specify the arguments in such a way:
`python arg1 arg2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

Same would work for `Python3` as well, you don't need to change anything. But as a safe practice, do check for the arguments length. You don't want to crash your script. Good luck.